# inserting link to a tag in javascript

Tags: javascript

i try to inserting `<a>` tag in `class1` before `<lable>`  and after `</label>` close `</a>` tag.
my code

```
 <div class="class1>

<label  class="class2">test</label>

</div>
```

i want to after javascript effected, code output is look like to this

```
 <div class="class1>
<a>
<label  class="class2">test</label>
</a>                                                   
</div>
```

please help me to get this result.

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave us what you have tried code-wise to pull this off. There's a couple of ways to complete this task.

Comment: Step by step, I think: 1. get the element that you want wrapped in <a></a>, eg. using document.querySelector(), or findElementsByClassName. 2. Make a new <a> tag, and put it in the Dom, before or after your target. 3. Move your target to your newly created <a></a>

Comment: thats right.plesse give me a simple way to solve this problem.i am beginer in javascript

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is not a code writing service, it is expected that you at least attempt to code this yourself. If you still have problems, you can ask a specific question with a summary of what you tried and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For future reference, read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

my program in php get this result me

```
<div class="class1>

<label  class="class2">test</label>

</div>
```

i want to when label with this class in result of my php project,java script get change code to upper information i explained
please give me simple way of solution

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/nk50eLpv/

```
label2Elements = document.getElementsByClassName('class2');

for (var i=0; i<label2Elements.length; i++) {
  var elm = label2Elements[i];
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href="#";
  elm.parentNode.insertBefore(a, elm);
  a.appendChild(elm);
}
```